# Difference between map only and map-reduce application

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to develop a set of simple mapreduce application where I process some complex data from file using map-only and map-reduce application. I am seeing some failure in my serialization code when I try to run map-reduce application. It is happening when the system tries to write intermediate data after map step. Due to this, one of the mapper is failing. But the same mapper is successful when there is no reducer.

Is there any difference in mapper output step for map-only or map-reduce step in terms of writing results to the filesystem?

Comment: Quite plainly, you've given us *nothing* to go on.  It just sounds to me like there's a bug in your code somewhere, and that a good place to look for the bug will be in the output-serialization routine in your mapper.  (Or, perhaps, the input-serialization routine of your reducer.  Or both.)  Look for things like 'undefined values' in the stuff that you're asking to serialize.  Maybe a typo ... referring to a key that isn't there.  Clean your eyeglasses and look at that piece of code *one .. more .. time.*  :-)

Comment: `some failure in ***my*** serialization code` So how do you expect us to help when you don't show your code?

Comment: Thanks for your responses. Sorry for not posting my code earlier. My understanding is that the results after map phase will be serialized and it will be written to the filesystem. Whether there is a reducer step or not, serialization step does not depend on that.  But I was noticing the exception only when reducer was set to run after map. It is due to a bug in my serialization code. I figured it out. Thanks again for trying to help me.

Comment: Correct, because when you reduce, you DEserialize. So your read methods will be called.